# How to correctly annotate multi-word entities for an NER Model?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to build an NER model using a Bert-like model (probably one that's a multi language because my training data is in english but real data is in french)

My question is about the entities I'm trying to identify, All of them are composed of many words, they're usually seperatd by either a white space, comma, a dash or even a dot sometimes.

2 examples :

1. QLQ-BR23 :  which is composed of 2 abreviations and seperated by a dash
2. Functional Assessment of Cancer Therapy - Lung

I'm working on annotating my texts using Doccano but I'm not quite sure how manually anotate these words using the IOB scheme :

should I seperate the comma, dot, dash and so on from the words and treat it as part of the entity's name or should I keep the words attached by a comma and consider them as a whole entity? I guess it depends on how my bert like model will do the tokenizeation?

should it be something like this :

- "QLQ": B_ent
- "-": I_ent
- "BR23" : I_ent

or rather like this :

- QLQ-BR23 : B_ent